# what is the mean of "window.event.repeat" in vb script?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

```
Function SearchField_OnKeyDown()
If window.event.keyCode = 8 Then 
    If window.event.repeat Or Not Em(document.all("SearchField").value) Then
        lBackspaceExits = False
        window.clearTimeOut(cBackTimeoutID)
        cBackTimeoutID = window.setTimeout("ResetBackspaceExit()", 600)
    ElseIf lBackspaceExits Then
        window.history.back()
        lBackspaceExits = False
    End If
ElseIf window.event.keyCode = 13 Or _
       window.event.keyCode = 38 Or window.event.keyCode = 40 Or _
       window.event.keyCode = 33 Or window.event.keyCode = 34 Then 
    SearchField_OnKeyDown = document_onkeydown()
    Exit Function
End If

SearchField_OnKeyDown = True
End Function
```

can you explain how to convert above function to javascript ? speacialy I need to know how to convert following steps

```
 window.event.repeat
 window.clearTimeOut(cBackTimeoutID)
 window.setTimeout("ResetBackspaceExit()", 600)
 SearchField_OnKeyDown = document_onkeydown()
```

`event.repeat` is not working in javascript. return the `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.repeat` indicates, if the key fired the event is pressed continuosly, this is valid JS.

`window.clearTimeout()` is the same in JS, it clears the timeout assigned  to `cBackTimeoutID`.

The 3rd line needs a little fix:

```
window.setTimeout(ResetBackspaceExit, 600);
```

JavaScript syntax you can find at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript).

Comment: what is the javascript equavalant for `event.repeat`